# Detecting auth token expiration with Emberfire

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, emberfire

I have no issue with my firebase token expiring but I'd like to programmatically know about this so I can ensure the UI responds in an appropriate way when this happens.

In this situations I notice that I get the following message:

> resumeSession() was canceled: Auth token is expired.

How can an Ember SPA hook into this event?